# Divs displaying outside of container div

Tags: html

There is a strange issue in this simple html structure. Here is the html code

```
<body>
    <div class='DatePicker' style="display: inline-block">
        <div id="dayDiv" class='DayDiv BorderMe'>
            <div id='upArrowDivs' class="BorderMe" style='display: inline-block; height:10%;width:100%;'>
                <div class='UpArrowDiv BorderMe'>

                </div>
                <div class='UpArrowDiv BorderMe'>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here the two innermost divs are displaying outside of its parent div which has id "upArrowDivs". Here is the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/HsSLN/) where you can see whats going on in StyleSheet.

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: is this a clearfix issue?

Comment: @JanTuroň I want both the divs inside the parent div. Just to make the example more prominent, please use following [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HsSLN/5/)

Comment: @austin no not a clearfix issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to `.UpArrowDiv`

```
vertical-align: top;
```

see [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsSLN/6/)

Comment: Thanks dude, that solved the problem, but can u tell me why the parent div didn't require that allignment while the innermost divs do, is it something to do with display: inline-block?

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your css file

```
#upArrowDivs{overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/HsSLN/7/).

Addition to CSS:

```
#upArrowDivs{overflow:auto;}
```

You need to add an overflow for the same.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the options

1) Increase your height of "upArrowDivs"

2) Set Padding=0 for  "upArrowDivs" and margin=0 to innermost divs